# list exclude from date range in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have date range from 20.01.2019 to 30.01.2019 and I have list[] of dates which need to be excluded from that data range. Can someone please help?

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime  

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

#Start and End is a range of dates. 
start = date(2019, 1, 20)
end = date(2019, 1, 30)

for single_date in daterange(start, end):
  print(single_date)
```

List to exclude these dates:

```
mvv_list[]
print(*mvv_list, sep='\n')
```

List result:

```
Row(date=datetime.date(2019, 01, 22))
Row(date=datetime.date(2019, 01, 23))
```

Comment: join `left_anti`

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways I would think of doing it would be to only yield dates that aren't in your excludes. This would mean you would have to modify your generator in a way like this:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date, exclude):
    # where exclude is the list of dates you don't want
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        next_date = start_date + timedelta(n)
        if next_date not in exclude:
            yield next_date
```